# Shopify API Customer sort incorrectly unlike other resources(Product, Order, etc)

Tags: shopify

I am building a shopify app by using the Shopify API, and run into trouble.

When I make a GET request with '/admin/customers.json'
Shopify API response with results sort incorrectly unlike other resources(Product, Order, etc)

I make some screenshots to  get thething clear.

[image]

[image]

[image: not order_by updated_at desc]

Both Order and Product reponse with the correct collection result("updated_at desc") but Customer didn't.

Is it bug or did I miss anything?

Comment: Yep. I just came across the same bug. Although, technically, this 'order' field is not documented anywhere as far as I can see... Did you end up finding a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to encode your parameters. Shopify docs don't show encoded params for clarity but you need:

```
'?fields='+encodeURIComponent('id,updated_at')+
'&updated_at_min='+encodeURIComponent('2015-11-25 20:01:00')+
'&order='+ encodeURIComponent('updated_at DESC');
```

Comment: Yeah I have tried, but the response is     "Attempt to order records by unknown orders updated_at%20desc, expected [:updated_at, :created_at]": "Required parameter missing or invalid", I think the point is not here the params encode, bcoz the problem is only for  'Customer' not others

Comment: It's a bug then. shopify throws a 400 error if you leave off asc or desc but when they are supplied it doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the search endpoint on customer.

```
/admin/customers/search.json
/admin/customers/search.json?order=updated_at DESC&fields=id
```

See the doc on the same API page as customer, just a bit further down the page

https://docs.shopify.com/api/customer

Comment: yes, I saw that search api, but it doesn't work with updated_at_min or created_at_min, like `/admin/customers.json` does.

Answer (score 0):

Use the 'sorty_by' attribute when doing your search: https://shopify.github.io/js-buy-sdk/api/classes/ShopClient.html#method-fetchQueryCollections